# Adjust recent activity page to show more then the top five posts

Tags: support, recent-activity

I would like to know if it's possible to see more then just the top five posts on the recent activity page, and if it's not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking a different tab than "summary".

[image: look ma, freehand circles]

Comment: Blah. I knew I was forgetting something.